# what is the meaning of $Id$ at the head of module files?

Tags: 7

I have seen this line at the head of many files in Drupal modules:

```
; $Id$
```

what the meaning of it? What does it do?
Is it important ? Should I put it when I am writing my own module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its legacy left behind of a no longer used version control system (CVS) used by Drupal.org/projects *before* the current  version control system (git) was [adopted](http://drupal.org/community-initiatives/git).

You should *not* use this when writing your own code.  The automated code checker tool at Drupal.org will actually [complain](http://drupal.org/node/990940) if these are present.

And, btw: Git rules!

Answer (score 4):

Its a keyword which is used by version control system. Whenever a file is checked in, it will replace that keyword with info related to file. There are other keywords such as [Date, Author, Revision ...](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).

> **Id**
>
> This keyword is a compressed combination of the other keywords. Its
> substitution looks something like $Id: calc.c 148 2006-07-28 21:30:43Z
> sally $, and is interpreted to mean that the file calc.c was last
> changed in revision 148 on the evening of July 28, 2006 by the user
> sally.

If you are using SVN which supports keyword substitution you can use that. It will help you identify easily last modified date and by whom. So you know whom to blame when something goes wrong ;)